Ошибка при запуске .pyd в встроенном python с Qt5 и Qtweb
у меня есть python скрипт скомпилированный в .pyd, его я собираюсь использовать в C++ приложении, для чего я и создал встроенную python 3.8 среду, чтобы программа могла переноситься.
В Программе используются импорты:
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets, QtWebChannel
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

В встроенном python установлены pyqt5==5.15.4 и PyQtWebEngine==5.15.6
После этого я пытаюсь запустить свою программу из c++ используя встроенный python и получаю ошибку:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtWebEngineWidgets: Не найден указанный модуль.

Советы в интернете о создании 'qt.conf' не помогают, помогает лишь совет с переименовыванием папки ../PyQt5/Qt5 -> ../PyQt5/Qt, но после этого я получаю новую ошибку:
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing QtCore: Не найдена указанная процедура.

Ее можно исправить, как пишут в интернете, только переустановкой PyQt5.
Мне нужна помощь, чтобы понять, как объединить это все, чтобы заработало мое приложение

Решено. Я почему-то не учитывал этого, но нашёл на одном из форумов информацию, что если путь содержит любые буквы кроме английских, то появляется такая ошибка.
Решение должно было работать через qt.conf, но почему-то мне это не помогало, помогло лишь изменение пути на чисто английский, без каких-либо других символов.
надеюсь, это поможет ещё кому-нибудь.
